# trying to order 3 values from least to greatest C++

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes numbers that a person enters and sums it. 
This happens 3 times, so I have 3 totals. The problem I am having is that I need to order them from greatest to least no matter what the sums come out to be.(this isnt the full code assume the sums are calculated and are declared)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 


using namespace std; 

string firstName1, lastName1;   // input and output for the users names

    string firstName2, lastName2;

    string firstName3, lastName3;
// from greatest to least
if ( sum > sum_2 > sum_3 )
    {
        cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName1 << " " << lastName1 << " " << "$" << sum << ".00" << endl;
        cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName2 << " " << lastName2 << " " << "$" << sum_2 << ".00" << endl;
        cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName3 << " " << lastName3 << " " << "$" << sum_3 << ".00" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++, the syntax `sum > sum_2 > sum_3` won't evaluate as you're assuming.  It's equivalent to `(sum > sum_2) > sum_3`.

In the case where `sum` is greater than `sum_2`, `sum > sum_2` will evaluate to true.  Then, this boolean value will be converted to an integer, 1 and compared with `sum_3`.

To do what you're trying to accomplish try:

```
if (sum > sum_2 && sum_2 > sum_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper swap function:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

And bubble sort it:

```
int sums[3] = { sum, sum_2, sum_3 };

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; ++j )
        if ( sums[j] < sums[i] ) 
            swap( &sums[j], &sums[i] );

cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName1 << " " << lastName1 << " " << "$" << sums[0] << ".00" << endl;
cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName2 << " " << lastName2 << " " << "$" << sums[1] << ".00" << endl;
cout << "Total for" << " " << firstName3 << " " << lastName3 << " " << "$" << sums[2] << ".00" << endl;
```